# creating multiple columns with <div><ul> and <li>

Tags: html

just got stuck when creating multiple columns with

.tried several ways but could not make it appropriate.

```
<h3>Staff / Administration</h3>
<div align="center" class="center-content"><ul style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CFCFCF;"><strong>Administration</strong><br /></div>
<div class="page-style"><ul style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CFCFCF;">

<li style="width: 15%; text-align: left;"><b>NICK</b></li>
<li style="width:12%; text-align: left;"><em>Chief Executive Officer</em></li>
<li style='width:12%; text-align: center'><em>Demos</em></li>
            <li style='width:12%; text-align: center'>Maps</li>
            <li style='width:12%; text-align: center'>Movies</li>
            <li style='width:12%; text-align: center'>Server</li>
            <li style='width:12%; text-align: center'>Website</li>
</ul></div>
```

desired output is

```
Staff / Administration


                            administration
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

NICK  Chief Executive Officer    Demos    Maps    Movies   server   Website
```

Comment: So why not use `table` for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mr. Alien suggests, it might be more appropriate to use a table for this sort of information.

However, if you're sure you want to use a list, you can style the individual list items to either float, or flow as inline blocks. My personally preferred method is inline-block. The example below is slightly reformatted from yours, and I've pulled the inline-block styling out into an inline CSS block.

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul.adminTable > li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
<h3>Staff / Administration</h3>
<div align="center" class="center-content"><ul style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CFCFCF;"><strong>Administration</strong><br /></div>
<div class="page-style">
    <ul style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CFCFCF;" class="adminTable">
        <li style="width: 15%; text-align: left;"><b>NICK</b></li>
        <li style="width:12%; text-align: left;"><em>Chief Executive Officer</em></li>
        <li style='width:12%; text-align: center'><em>Demos</em></li>
        <li style='width:12%; text-align: center'>Maps</li>
        <li style='width:12%; text-align: center'>Movies</li>
        <li style='width:12%; text-align: center'>Server</li>
        <li style='width:12%; text-align: center'>Website</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mr. Alien suggested, just use the `<table>` element for this:

```
<h3>Staff / Administration</h3>
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="7">
            Administration
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Nick
        </th>
        <td>
            <em>Chief Executive Officer</em>
        </td>
        <td>
            <em>Demos</em>
        </td>
        <td>
            Maps
        </td>
        <td>
            Movies
        </td>
        <td>
            Server
        </td>
        <td>
            Website
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You use tabular-data after all, so definally the way to go.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQpJ8/1)

Answer (score 0):

I cleared up some of your invalid html code and added following css:

```
.page-style{
    vertical-align: top;
}

ul {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.administration-title {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

See demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/T5t7q/